# What is the svn command-line equivalent to TortoiseSVN cleanup options that blow away all local changes?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN has a cleanup dialog that looks like this:

[image]

What is the command-line equivalent for the last three options? I use those when I want to achieve a fresh checkout.

The [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html#tsvn-cli-cleanup) docs don't list anything other than `svn cleanup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Delete unversioned files and folders

Use the [`--remove-unversioned` option](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-cleanup-options) with the `svn cleanup` command.

> Delete ignored files and folders
>   Revert all changes recursively

Use the [`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) command.

**IMPORTANT:** Use these commands with caution - the result is irreversible.